# Is it possible to make use of a list from an object by its object type?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to delete items from different lists og objects. 
I have the below classes, in my case I will be given the the object name of the list and then I will be required to delete items from that list. Is it possible to access a specific list only by its object type?

As an example I will be given "TestSubcolleciton" and then i will have to access Subcollecitons list in order to delete some records.

```
       private class TestClassWithSubcollection : BaseObject
        {
            public List<TestSubcolleciton> Subcollecitons { get; set; }

            public List<TestSubcollecitonSecond> SubcollecitonSeconds { get; set; }
        }

        protected class TestSubcolleciton
        {
            protected int Id { get; set; }
        }

        protected class TestSubcollecitonSecond
        {
            protected int Id { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Yes, you can, with reflection. Note that you have a typo in most uses of "Collection" here (should be **tion** at the end, not **iton**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using reflection, though this is probably a bad idea.

```
public static IList GetListByItemType(object instance, Type listItemType)
{
    if(instance == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("instance");
    if(listItemType == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("listItemType");

    Type genericListType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(listItemType);
    PropertyInfo property = instance.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.PropertyType == genericListType);
    if(property != null)
      return (IList)property.GetValue(instance);
    return null;
}
```

This either returns null or the first reference of a List found.

You can then use it like this:

```
TestClassWithSubcollection instance = ...

IList list = GetListByItemType(instance, typeof(TestSubcollecitonSecond));

if(list != null)
{
    // ...
}
```

---

If you need to get it by "Type name" of the list Item then do it like this:

```
public static IList GetListByItemType(object instance, string listItemTypeName)
{
    if(instance == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("instance");
    if(listItemTypeName== null) throw new ArgumentNullException("listItemTypeName");


    PropertyInfo property = instance.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType && p.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0].Name== listItemTypeName);

    if(property != null)
        return (IList)property.GetValue(instance);
    return null;
}
```

This is then used like this:

```
IList list = GetListByItemType(instance, "TestSubcollecitonSecond");

if(list != null)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I have tried the second piece of code but i'm getting an error at `property => property.IsGenericType` (Cannot resolve symbol).

Comment: Try now. Fixed some naming. Was writing this from the top of my head.

Comment: Im still receiving the same error `Cannot resolve symbol IsGenericType`. I checked my PropertyInfo class and there is no variable named `IsGenericType`

Comment: Now it is fixed. Otherwise wait till i am home to fix it in visual studio

Comment: Thanks that seems to have solved the problem. Ill test it out.